# Angular - access ngFor variable within a nested object

Tags: javascript, html, angular, syntax

I have accessed to a variable called **key** in this html element. How do I put the key inside of the

`*ngIf below: *ngIf="isSubmitted && errors.key.translations"`, especially the `errors.key.translation` part.

```
<div class="form-group col" *ngFor="let key of matchingKeys">
    <div
        *ngIf="isSubmitted && errors.key.translations"
        class="invalid-feedback"
    >       
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean access whatever `isSubmitted && errors.key.translations` gives inside the `div`?

Comment: No, I mean that `errors.key.translations` does not work. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Try `errors[key].translations`

Comment: @AntonÖdman that syntax is correct. Are you getting any error?

Comment: Michael's snippet should work fine: `errors[key].translations`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace dot with brackets. It should allow to access properties by name stored in a variable. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4968460/6513921). The following code should do it

```
<div *ngFor="let key of matchingKeys">
  <div *ngIf="isSubmitted && errors[key].translations">
    <p>
      {{ key }}
    </p>
  </div>       
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9y16uv)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="form-group col" *ngFor="let key of matchingKeys">
    <div
        *ngIf="isSubmitted && errors[key]['translations']"
        class="invalid-feedback"
    >       
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming matchingKeys are the keys to get error..

Try:

```
*ngIf="isSubmitted && errors[key].translations"
```